# Zend framework rememberMe without bootstrap

Tags: session, zend-framework, remember-me

I have app, in ZF1, where is not bootstrap. In config I have:

```
resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../tmp/session"
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 315360000
resources.session.gc_maxlifetime = 315360000
```

Folder tmp/session is set on 0777

In login controller before redirect on admin url (after logged) I have

```
Zend_Session::rememberMe();
```

In folder tmp/session was not created any file and app is automatically logouted after 1 hour. How can I init session resources from config without bootstrap?

Comment: It looks like that has not solution. Is now way to do that without bootstraping?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not bootstraping, you need to load the session settings manually:

You could use:

```
$configFilepath = '/path/to/application.ini';
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini($configFilepath);
$settings = $config->toArray();

Zend_Session::setOptions($settings['resources']['session']);
```

- ["Zend_Config_Ini" documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html)